# Using CPLEX with C++

Tags: c++, cplex

In fact, I am a beginner with c++ and I try to write a code to resolve the P-médian problem.

When I use the CPLEX interface, I get the optimal solution but it is not the case when I try to run my code in C++ that call CPLEX.

So I think that the problem in the writing of my code.

Thanks for you in advance.

Best regards,

N.B. : this is my code in C++:

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
ILOSTLBEGIN
int main (void) {
IloEnv env;
IloModel model(env);
IloNumVarArray var(env);
try {


int P=2;
int Noeuds=10;
float distance[10][10]={
{0,3.605551275,7,10.77032961,10.04987562,25,27.45906044,26.92582404,31.6227766,23.43074903},
{3.605551275,0,4.472135955,7.280109889,7.071067812,24.04163056,26.2488095,25.05992817,29.54657341,20},
{7,4.472135955,0,5,3.16227766,19.84943324,21.9317122,20.59126028,25.07987241,19.6977156},
{10.77032961,7.280109889,5,0,3,21.47091055,23.02172887,20.51828453,24.41311123,14.86606875},
{10.04987562,7.071067812,3.16227766,3,0,18.86796226,20.61552813,18.60107524,22.82542442,17.72004515},
{25,24.04163056,19.84943324,21.47091055,18.86796226,0,3,7.071067812,11.18033989,33.37663854},
{27.45906044,26.2488095,21.9317122,23.02172887,20.61552813,3,0,5.385164807,8.602325267,33.95585369},
{26.92582404,25.05992817,20.59126028,20.51828453,18.60107524,7.071067812,5.385164807,0,5,29.73213749},
{31.6227766,29.54657341,25.07987241,24.41311123,22.82542442,11.18033989,8.602325267,5,0,31.76476035},
{23.43074903,20,19.6977156,14.86606875,17.72004515,33.37663854,33.95585369,29.73213749,31.76476035,0}};

//cluster = IloNumVarArray(env, P);
IloNumVarArray cluster;
//Noeudsincluster = IloNumVarArray(env, P);
typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> IloNumVarArray2 ;
IloNumVarArray2 Noeudsincluster(env,Noeuds);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < P; i++){
        cluster[i] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOINT);
        }

for(IloInt i = 0; i < Noeuds; i++){
    Noeudsincluster[i]=IloNumVarArray(env,P);
        for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++){
            Noeudsincluster[i][k] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOINT);
        }
    }
//Sum (c in clusters) Noeudsincluster[n][c]==1
for(IloInt i = 0; i < Noeuds; i++){
        IloExpr expr(env);
        for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++)
        {
            expr += Noeudsincluster[i][k];
            IloConstraint c2 = (expr == 1);
            stringstream c2_name;
            c2_name << "Cons(2)[" << i << "]";
            c2.setName(c2_name.str().c_str());
            model.add(c2);
        }
}
//Sum (c in clusters) cluster[c]==P
        IloExpr expr(env);
        for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++)
        {
            expr += cluster[k];
        }
        IloConstraint c3 = (expr == P);
        stringstream c3_name;
        c3.setName(c3_name.str().c_str());
        model.add(c3);
//Noeudsincluster[n][c] <=cluster[c]
        for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++)
        for(IloInt i = 0; i < Noeuds; i++)
        {
            IloConstraint c1 = (Noeudsincluster[i][k]<=cluster[k]);
            stringstream c1_name;
            c1_name << "Cons(1)[" << i << "]" << "[" << k << "]";
            c1.setName(c1_name.str().c_str());
            model.add(c1);
        }


IloExpr Objective(env);
for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++)
    for(IloInt i = 0; i < Noeuds; i++)
        for(IloInt j = 0; j < Noeuds; j++)
            if(i!=j)
                Objective+=distance[i][j]*Noeudsincluster[i][k]*Noeudsincluster[j][k];
// Adding objective function
    model.add(IloMinimize(env, Objective));



IloCplex cplex(model);
cplex.solve();
env.out() << "Solution status = " << cplex.getStatus() << endl;
env.out() << "Solution value = " << cplex.getObjValue() << endl;

}
catch (IloException& e) {
cerr << "Concert exception caught: " << e << endl;
}
catch (...) {
cerr << "Unknown exception caught" << endl;
}

env.end();
return 0;
}
```

And this is my CPLEX .mod file :

```
//Data
int P = ...;//Nombre des clusters
int n = ...;//nombre des noeuds
range Noeuds = 1..n; //Ensemble des noeuds
range Clusters=1..P; //Ensemble des clusters

tuple edge {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges = {<i,j> |i,j in Noeuds};
float d[Edges] = ...;


//Variables
dvar boolean cluster[Clusters];
dvar boolean Noeudsincluster[Noeuds][Clusters];


//Objective
minimize sum(i in Noeuds ,j in Noeuds :i!=j, c in Clusters) d[<i,j>]*Noeudsincluster[i][c]*Noeudsincluster[j][c];

//Constraints
subject to {
//chaque noeud appartient à un seul cluster  
  forall( n in Noeuds )
    sum( c in Clusters ) Noeudsincluster[n][c] == 1;
//Nombre des clusters égale P
    sum( c in Clusters ) cluster[c] == P;

  forall( n in Noeuds , c in Clusters )
      Noeudsincluster[n][c] <= cluster[c];
  }
```

Comment: There are a bunch of options which set for finding a solution. That sometimes depends for on the modeling language you use (for example AMPL has it options that might differ from other languages). You could check the options and try to set them in you c++ as well.

Comment: thanks Sascha for your response. In fact, my model in CPLEX works very well, but the problem is in the conversion of our model from (. mod and.DAT) to.cpp so if you can help me, I will appreciate it

Comment: As a general model debugging tool, it is very helpful to save the model from CPLEX as an LP-format file. This is reasonably human-readable, and can help you check that you have got the constraints and variables in youir model that you expect. I think from memory its something like cplex.exportModel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to sum up `Noeudsincluster` first and then add `c2` constraint.

```
//Sum (c in clusters) Noeudsincluster[n][c]==1
for(IloInt i = 0; i < Noeuds; i++){
        IloExpr expr(env);
        for(IloInt k = 0; k < P; k++)
        {
            expr += Noeudsincluster[i][k];
        }
        IloConstraint c2 = (expr == 1);
        stringstream c2_name;
        c2_name << "Cons(2)[" << i << "]";
        c2.setName(c2_name.str().c_str());
        model.add(c2);
}
```